# Google sheets prompt for date input based on a data validation selection

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```html
else if(s.getName() == "Current Sales" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Parts Order Confirmed") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    
      if(!s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 12).getValue()) {
        
        s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 12).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireDate().setAllowInvalid(false))
      }
     
        s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 10).setValue('Pending Arrival');
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pending Orders");

        if(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 10 > targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {

                                                                  // Removed '10' and replaced with a calculation to add the right number of rows
            targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), (targetSheet.getLastRow() + 11) - targetSheet.getMaxRows()); 
        }
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);         
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearContent();
    var arr = s.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=arr.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
      Logger.log(arr[i][0].toString());
        if(arr[i][0].toString() == '') {
          Logger.log('Deleting row ' + i);
          s.deleteRow(i+1);
        }
      }
    s.getRange(2, 1, s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 9, ascending: true});
      targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow(),targetSheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 9, ascending: false});
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('File Copy of P.O. In I Drive!!!.');
  }
```

```html
function updateSheet(e) {
  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var r = ss.getActiveRange();


else if(s.getName() == "Current Sales" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Parts Order Confirmed") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    
      if(!s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 12).getValue()) {
        
        s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 12).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireDate().setAllowInvalid(false))
      }
```

Is there a way to prompt for a date selection in one cell if a certain data validation is selected in another cell?

I have used jqueryui.com to get HTML date picker but I have been unsuccessful in being able to return the selected date back into the sheet.

here is the code I currently have for this. Instead of a browser.inputBox I would like to have a popup calendar to pick a date from.

```html
else if(s.getName() == "Current Sales" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Parts Order Confirmed") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      if(!s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 12).getValue()) {
      var response = Browser.inputBox('Part ETA','Please Enter Part ETA', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
      if (response !== 'cancel') {
      Logger.log('Part ETA Is',response);
      Browser.msgBox('Part ETA Is ' + response);
      s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 12).setValue(response);
    } else if (response == 'cancel') {
      Logger.log('canceled.');
      Browser.msgBox('No date entered.');
    }
      }
```

Comment: Not if a certain cell is selected.  You could launch a dialog if a certain cell is edited and if you put a check box in that cell all you would have to do is click on it once and that would generate an onEdit event.  You could then launch a dialog with SpreadsheetApp.getUi...modal or modeless upon which you could build the DatePicker with JQuery UI  and return the date back with google.script.run.

Answer (score 2):

```
SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getRange(row, 12)
  .setDataValidation(
    SpreadsheetApp
      .newDataValidation()
      .requireDate()
      .setAllowInvalid(false)
  )
```

This will create a DataValidation of a required date on the cell you are currently setting the response in.  When a Date DataValidation is set you can double click on the cell and it will pop up a calendar.

[image: in cell pop up calendar example]

Comment: The Calendar helper also is shown when a cell having a date is edited.

Comment: I added my attempt to your code to the original post. It is not prompting.

Answer (score 1):

## Launching an html Dialog with one click on a Cell

> > Note: The cell must contain a checkbox.

The start trigger function to setup onEdit():

```
function startTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().indexOf('launchDialog')==-1){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('launchDialog').forSpreadsheet(getGlobal('SSId')).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

The actual dialog launcher:

You would probably want to use the HtmlService with a file and build your JQuery UI in there.  And then return the answer back to the server with google.script.run and with the success handlers you could remove the dialog via google.script.host.close().

```
function launchDialog1(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Hello World</h1>');//Replace with createHtmlOuput with a file instead of a string.  Build JQuery UI there.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'title');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F6').setValue(true);//reset the checkbox
}
```

The onEdit function:

```
function launchDialog(e){
  Logger.log('Range: %s SheetName: %s',e.range.getA1Notation(),e.range.getSheet().getName());
  if(e.range.getA1Notation()=='F6' && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='CheckBoxes'){
    launchDialog1();
  }
}
```

- References
- [Client To Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)
- [UI Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Here's the HTML/Javascript for the JQuery DatePicker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  function getDate(){
    var dt=$('#datepicker').val();
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
    .postDate(dt);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="getDate();" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

I got most of it from [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Here's the postDate() Google Script function:

```
function postDate(dt){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  var dtA=dt.split('/');
  rg.setValue(new Date(dtA[2],dtA[0],dtA[1]));
  return true;
}
```

This is the Google Script Code for setting up the trigger and for handling the onEdit functions:

```
function setupEditTrigger(funcName) {  
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().indexOf(funcName)==-1){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).forSpreadsheet(getGlobal('SSId')).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function checkForDate(e){
  Logger.clear();
  var chkbxcol=10;
  var sheetName='CheckBoxes';
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var shName=sh.getName();
  var row=e.range.getRow();
  var col=e.range.getColumn();
  Logger.log('shName: %s row: %s col: %s',shName,row,col);
  if(shName==sheetName && col==chkbxcol){
   var prevCell=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue(); 
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(prevCell) === '[object Date]'){
      sh.getRange(row,col).setValue("FALSE");
      return;
    }else{
      e.range.offset(0,-1).activate();
      sh.getRange(row,col).setValue("FALSE");
      showDatePickerDialog();
    }

  }else{
    return;
  }
}  

function setupOnEdit(){
  setupEditTrigger('checkForDate');
}
```

And this is what my test spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

I just created a column of checkboxes which trigger the onEdit the I check it the cell to the left of it has a date in it.  If it does I set the checkbox to false and return.  If it doesn't I launch the dialog and the date is returned to the cell next to the checkbox.  I return true which returns to the withSuccessHandler callback and closes the dialog.

Comment: I could not get any of the JQuery date pickers to return a selection, they just showed a calendar to which you could click a date but then it will not return into the sheet.

Comment: I’ll take a look at it and see if I can get it to work. But don’t you think the other answer is the way to go?

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the response Tom posted to work with prompting for datavalidation however I am having difficulties with getting this to work. I posted my take on his code up above. This would be a much simpler way than setting up a HTML script.

Comment: I wonder if it’s not working because of your onedit trigger. Try removing the onEdit. I tried it last night and it’s a pretty simple solution.

Comment: is there a way I can share my sheet for you to see?, its a small part in a bigger part of code, I need it to check if there is a date and if not then run this code to prompt for date datavalidation.

Comment: I've been able to get the code to fire as best as I can see however it doesn't pop up a calendar window it just inserts a error validation that reads "DataValidationBuilder" . the code continues to run transferring the row to the target sheets without being prompted to enter a date before the code can finish

Comment: If you can share a link to your spreadsheet.  Set the sharing to public and remove private information.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12bzzExlHduWrKkmhWeJDskhkdc5LKECF4BjR8j-Tcy4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So now knowing that I can see the sheet . Can you describe again exactly what you want to happen on the spreadsheet and what sections of the updateSheet code will be impacted.

Comment: On Code.gs Lines 184 to 214 is the area being worked on. line 188 checks for if there is a date in column 12, if not then line 190 should prompt for a date, the goal is to get a pop up calendar to select a date from which then inputs that date into column 12 before the rest of the script finishes.

Comment: Take a look at the example I just posted to my answer and see if that helps you in any way.  I have to leave for a couple of hours. I'll return to this question then.

Comment: I added the HTML however I am still having trouble pausing the code to let a date selection take place and then return that date to the cell. I am not doing the checkbox method as the trigger I want for this to pop up is *if(!s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 12).getValue())* the code checks if there is a date and if not then pulls the HTML "date picker" to prompt for a date selection.

Comment: I changed some of the code but you better go back in there and check it out.  I added the postDate() function which is called by the DatePickerDialog.  So when you want to call the dialog make sure that you make the cell that you want the date to go to the active cell.  Then the postDate function will place the return date into the active cell.  Keep in mind you cannot send Date() types using google.script.run so instead I send the date as a string.  The postDate() function is at the bottom of the code.gs file.  Take a look how it rebuilds the date for you.

Comment: I also added a title parameter to the showDatePickerDialog function.  Take a look at the showDatePickerDialog function it's also at the bottom of code.gs

Comment: When I select "parts order confirmed" in column "O" it is not prompting anything in columnd "L"

Comment: You have a fairly complex onEdit function so I didn’t go in and debug it. What are you doing to debug it? Personally I use Logger.log a lot.

Comment: I appreciate the help immensely. However I was unsuccessful at getting this to work within my onEdit function.  This is a little passed my skill level.

Comment: Actually, I'm not surprised because your onEdit function is quite complex.  There limits on the script runtime and I thought they were much lower that for other scripts but I can't find a reference at this time.

Comment: I went with just a dialog box and manually input the date (12/26/2018) much easier than what I was trying to do. just cannot believe a date box is this hard to enable into my script.